# How can libusbx drivers be installed automatically along with the application using an installer?

Tags: windows, driver, inno-setup, libusb-1.0, winusb

I have written an application for a device and I used the [libusbx](http://libusbx.org/) library. I had to install the WinUSB driver using Zadig to run my application. Now, I am deploying my application using the [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) installer. How can I automatically install the WinUSB driver for the libusbx library?